# Is it possible to use the Controllers in a separate MVC project from a Web Api project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing, self-hosting

I am pretty new to API work. I have an ASP.NET Web API project that is self-hosted using OWIN. Then I made a separate ASP.NET MVC 5 project with Controllers and backend work for my API. I have no views within this project as I have no need, I am just returning JSON data from the endpoints. I found that the routes I have for my program MVC controllers/ routing works much better. When trying to use ApiController controllers within my Web Api project originally, I was met with a lot of headaches trying to make the routing work properly. MVC worked right out of the box for me as far as routing goes.

So how can I contact these Controllers/ routes that are in a separate MVC project while running from my self-hosted Web API project? I have read that Self Hosting MVC does not work so I was trying to figure out a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have separate out asp.net mvc project and asp.net web api project.  To run both multiple project at once in Visual Studio.  Follow the link below by right on Project Solution.

https://www.chroscielski.pl/run-multiple-projects-in-visual-studio-at-once/

Comment: This shows how to run both projects at once, but I am wondering how I can get my Web API project to communicate/ use my controllers I have set up in my separate MVC project.